# Localization with resource files not working

Tags: c#, globalization

I have 2 resource files:

- Resource.resx, which is public, and
- Resource.en-GB.resx, which is set to "No code generation" in a "Resources" folder.

They both contain the key "BtnConnecter" with the French value in Resource.resx and English value in Resource.en-GB.resx. In my view I use @Resource.BtnConnecter.

My Chrome is set in French, my IE set in English, but I always see the French value.

(Note that I have another C# project with localization working. I have English values in IE, and French values in Chrome. The problem is not in the navigator configuration.)

What did I miss?

Comment: I know it's obivous, but are you sure you're setting culture to the current thread like this? `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;` and that `cultureName` is correct?

Comment: Actually this was not obvious to me as i'm a beginer, that's what i missed, thx :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you modified your Web.config to support globalization? Specifically, the `culture`, `uiCulture`, and `enableClientBasedCulture` attributes.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" enableClientBasedCulture="true" />
```

More information about this attribute can be found in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508(v=vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things to check: First, is your IE set to en-GB, or en-US (or just en)?  You might try renaming your english resx to '.en.resx' instead.  This would help because the resx files cascade.  If it cannot find a resx file for 'en-US' when that is the language, it will look for 'en' before resorting to the default.  So you would be better off with language-specific resx files instead of culture-specific ones.

Second, it is possible that you need to specify 'BtnConnecter.Text' in your resx file, not just 'Btn.Connecter'.  This is because there are frequently multiple parts of a control that need globalization, so the format 'control.property' is used as the key, not simply 'control'.

Lastly, if you have a functional project that is working, I would compare the two.  There may be a difference between them that needs to be fixed.  I'd double-check the build-action property on your resx files and your 'Copy to Output Directory' property.

Comment: I've renamed my english file to Resource.en.resx, VS says that i cannot use BtnConnecter.Text (The resource name 'BtnConnecter.Text' is not a valid identifier' and i've compared with the other project, set same build action and copy to output directory properties but nothing changed :/

Comment: @Lempkin: You might need to set the name of the resource to 'PageName'.en.resx, where 'PageName' is the name of the page (so, 'Index.aspx.en.resx', yes?  Also, see the answer by Will and comment by Orif.  If you don't have localization enabled and culture set, you won't see any changes.